# Multiple inputTypes won't do numberSigned and numberDecimal simultaneously

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-keypad, android-inputtype

For a few specific fields on my app the user needs to be able to enter a number that uses both decimals and negatives. However, the keyboard that shows up for the EditText now only shows the negative sign and no option for a decimal.

This seems to specifically an issue with the model of tablet and it's firmware. The device is a Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.0 that is running Android 4.1.2. I have tested on a Samsung Galaxy Note 8.0 running Android 4.4.2, and it works there, but both negatives and decimals are handled with the same key. The biggest issue I need resolved here is the inability to be able to use both negatives and decimals on the Galaxy Tab.

I used:

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```

to attempt to set the ability to use both keyboard types.

Is there a different `inputType` that could achieve both negative and decimal numbers? Is there another way to achieve this same result? (I messed around with using digits, but was unable to get the desired results).

Comment: Have the same question.